# Is template-name<TT> a deduced context?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

[[temp.deduct.type] paragraph 8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#8) lists all deduced contexts, but it seems not to include *`template-name`*`<TT>` where *`template-name`* refers to a class template and `TT` refers to a template template argument. Is this a deduced context?

If it is, why?

If not, consider the following code:

```
template<template<typename> class U, template<typename> class V>
struct foo {};

template<template<typename> class U>
struct foo<U, U> {}; 

int main() {}
```

This code compiles [under Clang 7.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IyBNW2HyLYUkGdVn) and [GCC 8.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/voAtEJ2ChSrhKhA1), which means the compilers consider the partial specialization is more specialized than the primary template, which means `U` and `V` in the primary template are successfully deduced against `foo<U, U>`. Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: And I gotta tell you, the standard is really frustrating at times. [It seems to be taking us right back to where we started](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.order#1)

Comment: @StoryTeller Now there is no function **call**.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why that paragraph is frustrating.

Comment: This rule may cause some form of recursivity:[\[temp.deduct.type\]/21](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#21)

Comment: @xskxzr I have posted a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902008/5632316) but I may be wrong, review and critics are welcome.

Comment: @Oliv This paragraph applies when template argument is deduced against an argument **of a function call**, and there is no function call in my example.

Comment: @xskxzr Not even the synthetized function for partial ordering rule?

Comment: @Oliv The template arguments of the synthesized function are deduced against the type of the other function, not against arguments of a function call.

Comment: Looks like you found a standard bug. Both `template-name<TT>` and `TT<TT>` need to be in there. Really, they (almost) always have been, (hopefully) always will be. You'd be hard-pressed to find a reasonable compiler that doesn't support [something like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kqH576OwcB1fywN0), for example. This isn't by far the most serious issue in the Templates clause, but an issue nonetheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This paragraph is full of problems, including the one you pointed out. [Core issue 2328](https://wg21.link/CWG2328) has a nice list:

> The presentation style of 17.9.2.5 [temp.deduct.type] paragraph 8
>   results in a specification that is unclear, needlessly verbose, and
>   incomplete. Specific problems include:
>
> - What does it mean for `P` and `A` to have one of a set of forms? Do they both have to have that form? (That doesn't happen; typically,
>     only `P` contains template parameters)
> - In the introductory sentence, aren't `T`, `TT`, and `i` supposed to be the names of template parameters rather than template arguments?
> - In `T[i]`, it appears we can deduce `i`, but not `T` (`T` can only be deduced in the form `T[integer-constant]`)
> - What is an *`integer-constant`* supposed to be?
> - What is a *`cv-list`*?
> - Why can we not deduce `const T` from `T`? (Apparently you only get to deduce if both or neither type have a *`cv-list`*, whatever a
>     *`cv-list`* is.)
> - We have extreme redundancy because, for instance, there is no way to say “in `T (T::*)(T)`, you can deduce any of those `T`s, and it's OK
>     if some of the positions don't have a `T`”. So we have seven (!) forms
>     of that construct, for all cases except the one where none of the
>     three positions contain a `T`.
> - We have special case rules for pointers to member functions, even though they're not a special case and should be covered by the rule
>     for pointers to members and the rule for functions.
> - We do not allow deducing a template template parameter's value from a template template argument — there is a `TT<T>` form, a `TT<i>`
>     form, a `template-name<T>` form, and a
>     `template-name<i>` form, but no `TT<TT>` form
>     nor `template-name<TT>` form.

It looks like the editor managed to get rid of *`cv-list`*, at least, since the issue was filed. It's now just *`cv`*. (*`cv-list`* is kind of hilariously wrong, because [syntax] says that the *-list* suffix is for comma-separated lists...)

Comment: So rules to deduce template template argument should be also added? Seems a huge change.

Comment: @xskxzr Huge? Perhaps for the specification. Not for implementations.

Answer (score -1):

It's correct, `template-name<TT>` is *not* a deduced context. That's not relevant here. Plain `TT` *is* a deduced context, and that's what you have here

The deduced context `template-name<I>` for a non-type template parameter `I` means that you can deduce `5` when you have argument `Foo<5>` to parameter `Foo<I>`.

The reason `template-name<TT>` is not a deduced context is fairly simple. If `template-name<TT>` would be legal, then `template-name` would have to take a template template parameter. That means it itself would have to be a template template template ("TTT").  There's only so much recursion in the language definition.

[edit]
In your example, you are deducing `V` for `U` to see if it's a specialization. Both are template templates. You are not trying to deduce whether `Foo<U> is`Foo`. Therefore your deduced context is`TT`, not`template-name.`.

To answer point 2 of the comment, `TT` is a deduced context because that form is listed explicitly. And what `template-name<TT>` means is that `TT` would have to be deducable when `TT` is used as an argument to a known template. But what type of template accepts a template template parameter? That the hypothetical `TTT`.

Comment: 1. Do you mean it is a compiler bug for my example? 2. Why is plain `TT` a deduced context? 3. "That means it itself would have to be a template template template ("TTT"). " What do you mean by "it"? `template-name<TT>` itself is a specialization, not template.